# Using columns with special characters in formulae in R

Tags: r, special-characters

I'm trying to make a decision tree using rpart using a data frame that has ~200 columns. Some of these columns have numbers in their names, some have special characters (e.g. "/"). When I try to generate the tree I get error such as the ones below:

```
R> gg.rpart <- rpart(nospecialchar ~ Special/char, data=temp, method="class")
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Special' not found
R> gg.rpart <- rpart(nospecialchar ~ "Special/char", data=temp, method="class")
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid model formula in ExtractVars
R> gg.rpart <- rpart(nospecialchar ~ `Special/char`, data=temp, method="class")
Error in `[.data.frame`(frame, predictors) : undefined columns selected
```

Do I have to change the names to accommodate R or is there some way to pass column names with special characters to R formulae?

Comment: Complying with R's wishes is so easy, one line using make.names() that I'm not sure it's worth it to use the nonstandard names, even if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Joran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324364/joran)'s comment on my question is the answer - I didn't know of the existence of make.names()

Joran, if you reply as an answer I'll mark you as correct. Cheers!

Comment: HI Conor, would be great if your answer contained an example of how to use the make.names() function.

Answer (score 9):

This works:

```
dat <- data.frame(M=rnorm(10),'A/B'=1:10,check.names=F)

> lm(M~`A/B`,dat)

Call:
lm(formula = M ~ `A/B`, data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        `A/B`  
    -1.0494       0.1214
```

Comment: This works when I can specify the columns individually. In the example I gave there are over 200 columns, too many to specify individually.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same problem, and I don't want any change in the name when pass it to R formulae. R allow non-syntactic column names with backticks surrounding them. So I try add backticks to the name and it also works well. My code like below:

```
lapply(colnames(variable), function(gene){
formula0 <- paste0("gleason_grade", "~" "`", gene, "`")
logit <- clm(as.formula(formula0), data = mydata)
})
```

and now you can pass the new variable to formula without error.
If you don't expect any change to the variable like me, so just backtick it.

Comment: That doesn't work because `as.formula` is removing the backticks and the error goes on: ```as.formula(paste0("gleason_grade~", "`", "gene2", "`"))```

Comment: I have tried it with a non-syntactic name like this: `as.formula(paste0("gleason_grade~", "\`", "gene 2", "\`"))`, it'll keep these backticks.