# R : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, dplyr

I defined an ab vector as :

```
str(ab)
chr [1:11] "simplets" "mCD45+" "mCD3-" "mCD11+" "mMHCII+high" "mMHCII+low" "mGR1+" "mLY6C+" "mLY6G+" "mGR1-" ...`
```

and the following function:

```
addBackQuotes <- function(input) {
    return (paste0("`", input, "`"))
}
```

The following works :

```
test2$`mCD45+`
 [1] 0.6718366 0.6455138 0.6287242 0.4328270 0.7493678 0.6361139 0.5878209 0.6181456 0.6254296 0.6444584 0.6224044 0.8840796 0.6435837
```

but

```
> k <- test2 %>%        kruskal( as.formula(paste0("y =
> .$",addBackQuotes(ab[2]))),
>                  #y = .$`mCD45+`,
>                                trt = .$Group.short,
>                            alpha = 0.05,
>                            p.adj = "holm",
>                            group = FALSE)  %>%
              .$comparison
```

Gives me the following error:

> Error in .$`mCD45+` : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Typo remark : mCD45+ is correctly surrounded by backquotes.

Could you please explain what's happening ?

Comment: Possible duplicate / relevant post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272469/using-columns-with-special-characters-in-formulae-in-r

Comment: I am not sure what's going on there but maybe there could be a workaround?
Would `paste0("y ~ .[, ", ab[2], "]")` work? Also, are you sure the formula is supposed to be `y = ...` and not `y ~ ...`?

Comment: It would be much easier to to help if you provided a [reproducible example](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/#reprex) that we could easily run.

Comment: Milan, it finally works, replacing "=" by "~". I've always used this function with "=", I do not really understand. However, there is still an issue. Variable does not seem to be updated at each step of the loop. I always get the same result. Weirdly, when I print this variable, I can see that, it is correctly updated... I can not understand what's wrong here.