# I need to know why I get the error 'unexpected input in "p<-ggplot(data=mov2, aes(x=Genre,y=Gross % US))" '

Tags: r

I want to prepare the plot's data and aes layers. But this code doesn't run

```
p <- ggplot(data = mov2, aes(x = Genre, y = Gross % US))
```

when aes layers is taken off, it's working

```
p <- ggplot(data = mov2)

p <- ggplot(data = mov2, aes(x = Genre, y = Gross % US)) # this code got error
v <- ggplot(data = movies, aes(x = Genre, y = CriticRating)) #this code is working 

Error: unexpected input in "p<-ggplot(data=mov2, aes(x=Genre,y=Gross % US))"
```

Comment: The % symbol in the column name is the problem. Enclose it in backticks (`).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272469/using-columns-with-special-characters-in-formulae-in-r

Answer (score 4):

Most R code will get confused with columns that have spaces or weird symbols like `%`. You need to surround those with backticks to R knows that's supposed to be a column name. Try

```
p  <- ggplot(data=mov2, aes(x=Genre,y=`Gross % US`))
```